# Cloudboost File url is null for Android Java

Tags: java, android, cloudboost

I am having a little problem getting all of the file info from my Cloudboost file object. Here is the code that I am using to get the id, name and url of the file. The problem is that I can get back the id and the name; however, the url is is null and I don't know why or how to fix it. Any ideas??

```
class FileQuery extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        CloudQuery query = new CloudQuery("Pubs");
        query.include("file");
        query.equalTo("id", "U1YV132B");
        try {
            query.find(new CloudObjectArrayCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(CloudObject[] x, CloudException t) throws CloudException {
                    if (x != null) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                            final CloudFile f = new CloudFile(x[i].getDocument());
                            f.fetch(new CloudFileArrayCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(CloudFile[] x, CloudException t) throws CloudException {
                                    Log.d("dozer74", "File Id: " + f.getId()); // This will print out
                                    Log.d("dozer74", "File Name: " + f.getFileName()); // This will print out
                                    Log.d("dozer74", "File URL: " + f.getFileUrl()); // This is null
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (CloudException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is how I call this class

```
new FileQuery().execute();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming column `file` in table `Pubs` is actually of type `File` and you saved a `CloudFile` to `CloudBoost` before saving it to `Pubs`.
 
You should now access your `CloudFile` like this instead:

```
final CloudFile file=new CloudFile(x[i].getDocument().getJSONObject("file"));
```

This is because your line

```
final CloudFile f = new CloudFile(x[i].getDocument());
```

simply

1. returns the body of the `CloudObject`
2. creates `CloudFile` using the output of step #1 above

You are missing one step in between as indicated below:

1.get the body of `CloudObject`
  2. retrieve the body of a `CloudFile` under column `file` inside the `CloudObject`
3.  Create `CloudFile` using the ouput of step #2 above.
`CloudObject.getFile([columnName])` appears as one of the improvements to make this operation easier in JavaSDK-1.0.3 which you should be able to clone soon from the `CloudBoost` repo.